# Create Google apps script GUI for array outuput

Tags: javascript, arrays, user-interface, google-apps-script

I need to create a GUI for my array output in Google apps script. Googling for 3 hours and cant find solution on how to output array in google apps script. Any ideas please?

Comment: You have to be more specific and that might be the issue you are googling for 3 hours and you haven't found anything. Describe what is the input, what is the desired output. Provide some examples, screenshots, sheets or something more specific. Ideally we would expect from you some code (or some efforts) towards the solution.

Comment: Try this: `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModeLess(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(your.array.join('<br />')),"Title");`

Answer (score 1):

A GUI for your 2 dimensional array from a spreadsheet.

```
function guioutput() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const rg=sh.getDataRange();
  const vA=rg.getValues();
  var html='<style> th,td{border:1px solid black;}</style><table>'
  vA.forEach(function(r,i){
    html+='<tr>';
    r.forEach(function(c,j){
      if(i==0) {
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<th>%s</th>',c);
      } else {
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<td>%s</td>',c);
      }
    });
    html+='</tr>';
  });
  html+='</table>';
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html), "Your GUI is less than ten minutes")
}
```

Here's a table of data to test it on.

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 | COL10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21 | 24 | 2 | 24 | 21 | 18 | 24 | 20 | 3 | 19 |
| 4 | 23 | 3 | 17 | 16 | 5 | 18 | 7 | 5 | 12 |
| 1 | 8 | 5 | 9 | 5 | 9 | 22 | 5 | 12 | 14 |
| 18 | 10 | 21 | 5 | 2 | 23 | 13 | 4 | 2 | 12 |
| 15 | 1 | 6 | 17 | 0 | 18 | 20 | 22 | 2 | 18 |
| 14 | 13 | 13 | 12 | 23 | 9 | 16 | 20 | 5 | 6 |
| 18 | 0 | 11 | 23 | 23 | 5 | 10 | 24 | 19 | 18 |
| 13 | 2 | 9 | 10 | 19 | 8 | 3 | 10 | 24 | 6 |
| 4 | 10 | 19 | 4 | 16 | 22 | 11 | 16 | 11 | 3 |
| 8 | 13 | 17 | 17 | 10 | 23 | 21 | 10 | 6 | 15 |
| 7 | 5 | 18 | 15 | 14 | 1 | 19 | 24 | 5 | 21 |
| 23 | 4 | 10 | 3 | 20 | 9 | 24 | 0 | 19 | 23 |
| 18 | 2 | 19 | 1 | 2 | 16 | 3 | 6 | 16 | 7 |
| 13 | 19 | 7 | 1 | 7 | 1 | 18 | 20 | 18 | 6 |
| 16 | 19 | 10 | 1 | 6 | 20 | 2 | 6 | 21 | 16 |
| 12 | 24 | 12 | 20 | 9 | 12 | 4 | 14 | 15 | 21 |
| 21 | 2 | 18 | 6 | 18 | 19 | 15 | 10 | 11 | 0 |
| 24 | 3 | 1 | 10 | 19 | 24 | 18 | 21 | 1 | 10 |
| 16 | 12 | 18 | 18 | 4 | 5 | 23 | 13 | 9 | 17 |
| 4 | 13 | 3 | 22 | 8 | 6 | 1 | 3 | 11 | 2 |
| 21 | 20 | 8 | 1 | 4 | 18 | 7 | 21 | 22 | 7 |
| 23 | 12 | 13 | 0 | 22 | 22 | 9 | 22 | 6 | 1 |
| 0 | 24 | 21 | 24 | 14 | 12 | 16 | 6 | 17 | 12 |
| 17 | 1 | 2 | 20 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 24 | 10 |
| 15 | 17 | 3 | 18 | 5 | 16 | 9 | 2 | 15 | 11 |

And if you doit correctly you will get this:

[image]